# netcfg.yaml question

Tags: netplan

hello I just upgraded to ubuntu 18 and looking for help on converting this to work with netplan.

```
auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
    address 10.0.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.0.0.1 dev ens192
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to:

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6; no
      addresses: [10.0.0.2/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Then launch:

```
sudo netplan apply
```